# ActiveMQ real time configuration

Tags: java, c++, configuration, activemq-classic

I would like to change ActiveMQ configuration while it is running.

Let's say I want to increase the memory usage, flow control etc. while ActiveMQ is running, but i don't want to restart it. Is this possible? I tried it but the changes didn't kick in.

Is there a way to do this?

I do have C++ and java clients (producers and consumers respectively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ActiveMQ configuration can be changed at runtime via JMX. However, any changes that are made at runtime will not be persisted to the configuration file.

Comment: Is there a guide I can follow? Can JMX run on shell? or through ssh?

Comment: I actually see that you can connect to a remote host. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by bsnyder it you can change broker config at runtime with JMX. 
An easy way of doing this is to use JConsole to get to the broker's JMX Beans ([instructions here](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html)), there is also a JMX API if you need to this through code.